# set Focus on Top of screen jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page with multiple tabs and i Show and hide them based on a href click using jquery. Whenever I click on "a href", the page is scrolled down. Am trying to set the focus on the top of the page. This is my first project in Jquery. I tried the following but still doesnt work.

1. scroll(0, 0);
2. window.scrollTo(0,0);
3. window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
4. var ctrl = document.getElementById('lnkCreateJob');
           ctrl.focus();

please do share some light on that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(".gototop").click(function(){
    var focusElement = $("#contents");
    $(focusElement).focus();
    ScrollToTop(focusElement);
});

function ScrollToTop(el) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(el).offset().top - 50 }, 'slow');          
}
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/zhPtw/)

Comment: Hi A.K
I tried setting focus on a particular say a textbox after scrolling to top but am unable to do it.
Have u tried doing it? if so how?
I used  
var ctrl = document.getElementById('txtName');
ctrl.focus();
after ScrollToTop but its not working. plz do help

Answer (score 1):

Just use `<a href="#">Your link</a>`. It will take you to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a element (any html element ex div) with id="#" in the top of the page. you have to put this # in the href of the 'a' link.
Then, your method should be in onclick method of the 'a' link.