# Always go to the top of the previous page?

Tags: jquery, scroll, history, back

Is it possible to make the script scroll to the top of the previous page?  Right now the script returns to the previous page and in the middle of the body where the link was located.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.back').click(function(){
    parent.history.back();
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you have answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190132/set-focus-on-top-of-screen-jquery

Comment: Wow... I'm getting old.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjana83 Post it as an answer so it can be accepted and marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about any page, even outside your website/app, it's not possible.

As you don't have control over the previous page, you can't run any code there.
Adding `#top` or a hash and then going back to that page won't work.

If we're talking only inside a website you control, of course you can use JS to control that.